# using $_session and session_start() with int column

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to check how much time has elapsed since the session started and compare with my database column value in INT to see if it's expired and logout the user.
 in the place of inactive= 10; in my code below i want to pass the db column value either in INT

```
<?php require_once('Connections/noundb.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
 $inactive = 10; // Set timeout period in seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $inactive) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: l.php");
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();



// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "l.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Okay. And now ask a question!

Comment: compare the session with a database value not have it inside the page but pass the value to the session

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do session start before require once, and don't close and open php tags: this mean an output to send to the client,then no "managed" session can be started.

Try this:

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

require_once('Connections/noundb.php');
// [other code ]
```

Comment: Nice after this passing the value to my database table to compare the session with a database value not have it inside the page but pass the value to the session –